# how access Apache server on Ubuntu(10.0.0.6) from windows vista(10.0.0.9) inside local network?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, home-networking

I have Apache server on Ubuntu that i can access with 'localhost' - network local adress 10.0.0.6

I have windows vista with local adress 10.0.0.9.

I want to able access ubtunu 'localhost' from windows browser.

Edit:

1. I have access with the name 'mysite.ll' and not to 'localhost' - i just write for convience 'localhost'
2. I define in windows hosts file: `10.0.0.6 mysite.ll www.mysite.ll` + ipconfig /flushdns  - and then access from windows 'mysite.ll' but i get response: "Chrome could not connect to mysite.ll"

Update:
When i down the ubuntu firewall my windows access the ubuntu apache server.
What should i define in my ubuntu firewall (I use firestarter)?

Solution:
add new rule in firestarter

please help me

Comment: localhost is a loopback address for 127.0.0.1 which is the given machine in question.  Just use the 10.0.0.6 address DO NOT redirect localhost to 10.0.0.6 lots of programs assume that localhost IS 127.0.0.1

Comment: thanks, but also directly http://10.0.0.6 - not works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Apache server is running and accessible from the Ubuntu machine.

Then make sure the `ufw` firewall (`gufw` will work if you have a gui installed) has been configured to let traffic from other computers through port 80.